# highchart retrieve data from a stored procedure and parse to JS function

Tags: javascript, c#, highcharts

I have a JSFiddle which creates multiple charts together. Currently, this is hard coded data being plotted. I am trying to get the values from a SQL stored procedure and parse it to the JavaScript function using c# back-end code.

One way I understand is by using hidden variables to store the chart data and assign this to data: however don't know how loop through each row and put the data value to the high chart. The number of charts will vary depending on the SQL parameters so I can't hard code each JavaScript function to look at a specific `div` container as container numbers might differ... But not sure how to do this with multiple charts dynamically using a loop?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m18Lpfg9/)

I have tried the following but now I am stuck on next steps to loop through each row and call JavaScript:

.NET METHOD to get data for highchart:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cn.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int i = 0;
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string str = reader["ChartData"].ToString();
        string[] strList = str.Split(',');

        // convert it in json
        dataStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strList, Formatting.None);

        hiddenvariable.Value = dataStr;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have used a `highcharts` tag, but the problem is more related to your back-end code. I'm not a c# expert but is it possible to just put data from your c# code to the js variable? Or get it using AJAX?